# C++ Program Gets Crash on recalling Function from Main?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Movie` with data members `genre` `Actors` and `size`.

```
class Movie
{
private:
    string* Actors;
    string* genre;
    int size = 0;
```

I have used setters and getters method to initialize the data members. First I have set the size to 2 from main by calling the

```
setsize()
```

member function for `genre` and then called the member function

```
set_genre().
```

from main. Here comes the problem, whenever i re-call the

```
setsize()
```

for Actors and set the size for actors and Debug my program it takes input for both `genre` and `actors` but when it comes to display it crashes, displaying Exception thrown. I have tried so many things but i don't know how to resolve this problem. Please anyone help me with this, it's a task from my lab instructor.

CLASS...

```
class Movie
{
private:
    string* Actors;
    string* genre;
    int size = 0;
public:
    Movie()
    {
        Actors = new string[size];
        genre = new string[size];
    }
    void setsize(int x)
    {
        size = x;
    }
    void set_actors()
    {
        Actors = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "ACTOR " << i + 1 << endl;
            getline(cin, Actors[i]);
        }
    }
    void set_genre()
    {
        genre = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "GENRE " << i + 1 << endl;
            getline(cin, genre[i]);
        }
    }
    void display_actors()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << Actors[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    void display_genre()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << genre[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    ~Movie()
    {
        delete[]genre;
        delete[]Actors;
    }
};
```

MAIN...

```
Movie M1;
    M1.setsize(2);//GENRE SIZE SET TO 2
    M1.set_genre();
    M1.setsize(4);//ACTOR SIZE SET TO 4
    M1.set_actors();
    cout << "DISPLAYING DATA" << endl;
    M1.display_actors();
    M1.display_genre();
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please. Otherwise it's nearly impossible to diagnose your problem properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen. You set the size to 2, then read 2 genres. Then set the size to 4, read 4 actors, then display 4 actors, and then 4 genres. See the problem? How many genres are there? How big is the `genre`-array and how many elements do you read?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the `genre` size is 2 but when `actors` size set to 4 and when it comes to display `genre` display size gets to 4 too. So how do i set different sizes for different member functions?

Comment: Your `class Movie` don't follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and have risk of dangling pointer and double-free.

Comment: You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of manually allocated dynamic arrays to avoid memory problems.

Comment: Prepare different variables for sizes to set different sizes for different member functions.

Comment: Thanks:) @churill I have used another set size member function for `Actors` and it worked. Your comment helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Least fix will be preparing separate variables for

- size of current `Actors`
- size of current `genre`
- size for next reading

It will be like this:

```
class Movie
{
private:
    string* Actors;
    string* genre;
    int Actors_size = 0, genre_size = 0;
    int size = 0;
public:
    Movie()
    {
        Actors = new string[size];
        genre = new string[size];
    }
    void setsize(int x)
    {
        size = x;
    }
    void set_actors()
    {
        Actors = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "ACTOR " << i + 1 << endl;
            getline(cin, Actors[i]);
        }
        Actors_size = size;
    }
    void set_genre()
    {
        genre = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "GENRE " << i + 1 << endl;
            getline(cin, genre[i]);
        }
        genre_size = size;
    }
    void display_actors()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Actors_size; i++)
        {
            cout << Actors[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    void display_genre()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < genre_size; i++)
        {
            cout << genre[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    ~Movie()
    {
        delete[]genre;
        delete[]Actors;
    }
};
```

This code will at least work without crashing if instances of this class aren't copied, but have problems of memory leak (pointers to old arrays are thrown away without being freed) and have risk of using dangling pointers and double-free because it doesn't follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

To avoid many troubles of memory management, you shouldn't use manual allocation of dynamic arrays and you should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

It will be like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Movie
{
private:
    std::vector<string> Actors;
    std::vector<string> genre;
    // sizes are stored in the vectors, so no external size management is required
    int size = 0;
public:
    Movie()
    {
        // vectors will be implicitly initialized, so no explicit initialization is required
    }
    void setsize(int x)
    {
        size = x;
    }
    void set_actors()
    {
        Actors.resize(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "ACTOR " << i + 1 << endl;
            getline(cin, Actors[i]);
        }
    }
    void set_genre()
    {
        genre.resize(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "GENRE " << i + 1 << endl;
            getline(cin, genre[i]);
        }
        genre_size = size;
    }
    void display_actors()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Actors.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << Actors[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    void display_genre()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < genre.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << genre[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    ~Movie()
    {
        // explicit deallocation isn't also required
    }
};
```